# How to make Photoshop launch faster?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, windows

I have what I'd like to think is a top of the line Windows desktop, built recently.

- Ryzen 3950x processor
- Samsung 970 EVO Plus SSD (M.2 NVMe)
- 32GB of DDR4 3600 memory
- Win 10

Photoshop takes 13+ seconds to open, every time. My entire OS doesn't take much longer than this to load. Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: That’s more of a question for SuperUser stack exchange because it has nothing to do with graphic design. On a side note, why do you need to reopen it so often that it bothers you?

Comment: @Sergey agreed it has nothing to do with graphic design, but a heavy PS user is most likely to know the answer, if there is one. Many times I don't **need** to reopen the app, but in general I do many things in life that I don't need to. However there is one case where I most certainly **do** need to: PS has a very longstanding bug where sometimes even after closing all opened files, it still keeps a "handle" on them and prevents the OS from deleting them. In this case you need to close PS to be able to delete the files, and then reopen to continue working.

Comment: @The111 you're right to a certain point. But we can't answer because the cause for slowness might be something else in your specific hardware / software combination. Certainly my Photoshop takes 20+ seconds to open and I wouldn't expect anyone here to know exactly why.

Comment: How much is "lots" of RAM? Some people think 8GB is lots ;) For comparison, Ps takes about 6s to launch on my 2012 Mac Pro, so I'd suspect some Windows process is slowing it down.

Comment: Is it a fresh install? A number of fonts, extensions, tools and presets also have an influence on startup time. At work on an semi-ancient i5 it takes about 22s from clicking the icon to 'everything is loaded' state, my Photoshop is filled with extension panels though

Comment: 13 seconds..... I bet you stand in front of a microwave screaming "Hurry up!!!!!"`:)` To load faster, limit active system fonts and Photoshop lug ins.

Comment: @Luciano not asking anybody to say for sure why it takes a long time on my system. Just curious if there is any general advice for speedup that I'm not finding.

Comment: @Tetsujin it's 32GB, aka far more than PS needs at idle. Takes around 9 seconds on my 2015 Macbook Pro (also 32GB). I have no idea how much PS source code is shared between platforms though. The Win binary could be quite different. :-/

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy fresh install of both OS and PS. No addons installed in PS, just 100% stock.

Comment: @Scott no the microwave takes as long as I request. If it took as long to microwave things as it did to cook them in the oven though... I'd be perplexed. I use a lot of high end engineering software that has far steeper requirements than PS, and never have I had any application that takes as long as my OS to open. PS has always been like this unfortunately. Moving to NVMe made a lot of other apps open faster... no change with PS.

Comment: Tried at home: Win + 3700X@3.6ghz 8c/16t, 32 ram: 13s, OSX + MBP 2012@2.2ghz 4c/4t, 8gb ram: 12s :) I guess on Windows it's slower. Is this the reason why new Mac Pro exists?

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic solution. Try everything you can try:

- clean up everything you can in windows before worrying about what's wrong with Photoshop
- purge windows temp files
- test your SSD
- experiment with Photoshop's cache settings
- purge Bridge's cache and every cache folder you can get your hands on
- don't work with huge files
- pause any cloud syncing
- reinstall
- google this and see what other people are doing

My Photoshop CC loads in about 10 seconds, but I don't have a problem with that. It has never been quicker, maybe in CS6 days I could have gotten a 7-8 seconds load time. But who's counting? :)

Comment: Mine loads in about 4 seconds - from App click to Home screen, but i wouldn't be fazed if it took 5x as long, Geeez this generation wants everything NOW don't they. 1st world problems :)

Comment: @Mark Read which generation is that? And yes, most of the issues posted about here are by definition first-world problems. Impoverished people spend very little time  thinking about Photoshop.